# incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String

Tags: java, arrays

I'm being completely beaten up by types in Java.

I have coordinates in a txt file, which ultimately I want to format into an array of these co-ordinates, with each array item being a double.

Each line of my txt file looks like so:

```
13.716              , 6.576600074768066
```

Currently, I'm trying to split this line into an array of two Strings, which I will then try and parse into doubles, but I keep getting the error in the title.  Where am I going wrong?

Any other better approaches on converting my Arraylist of Strings to a formatted list of double coordinates would be great, like so

```
[[0,1], [0,2], 0,4]
```

Code:

```
 public static String[] getFileContents(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
//        Skips 1376 characters before accessing data
        reader.skip(1378);
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {            
                data.add(line);
//                System.out.println(line);
        }  

        for (int i=0; i < data.size(); i++){
            data.set(i, data.get(i).split(","));
        }
//        String[] dataArr = data.toArray(new String[data.size()]);
//        Test that dataArr[0] is correct
//        System.out.println(data.size()); 
//        List<String> formattedData = new ArrayList<String>();
//        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
//            formattedData.add(dataArr[i].split(","));
//        }
        reader.close(); 
        return dataArr;
    }
```

Comment: data.get(i).split(",") will return String[], you have to use index in order to get each token, access using index like this data.get(i).split(",")[0], data.get(i).split(",")[1];

Comment: or else declare your 'data' like this List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();

Comment: As other answer mentioned, the compilation error is simply due to you are adding of `split()` (which is a `String[]`) to a `List<String>`.  However, your code shows a lot more problems.  e.g. What you are returning is not making sense (returning String[], but you mentioned you want to parse the coordinates to double); A lot of unrelated code is included in the question etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `split(",")` method return array of string `string[]` and you can't set string by array of string.

Crate point class with `let lan double variabels` and then create array of this point and them fill them with data from reading each line:

```
class Point{
    double lat;
    double len;
    Point(double lat, double len){
        this.lat = lat;
        this.len = len;
    }
}
```

And then use this class in your code:

```
 public static String[] getFileContents(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
//        Skips 1376 characters before accessing data
        reader.skip(1378);
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {            
                data.add(line);
//                System.out.println(line);
        }  
        List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
        for (int i=0; i < data.size(); i++){
            double lat =  Double.parseDouble(data.get(i).split(",")[0]);

            double len =  Double.parseDouble(data.get(i).split(",")[1]);
            points.add(new Point(lat, len));
            //data.set(i, data.get(i).split(","));
        }
//        String[] dataArr = data.toArray(new String[data.size()]);
//        Test that dataArr[0] is correct
//        System.out.println(data.size()); 
//        List<String> formattedData = new ArrayList<String>();
//        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
//            formattedData.add(dataArr[i].split(","));
//        }
        reader.close(); 
        return dataArr;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Amin - I'd actually used the Point class elsewhere in my program but your solution makes more sense.  However, when I try and implement it I get the error - Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context, on the line of point.add(new...

Comment: Your welcome @scott_ this error because you try to use point class as inner class and if it be inner can't use it in static method of that class,

Comment: @scott_  the point class should not be in class that getFileContents method be in it

Answer (score 1):

you can update your while loop like this

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] splits = line.split(",");
    for(String s : splits) {
        data.add(s);
    }
}
```